# Spring mvc beans error Java Web Based config

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a spring mvc website but i'm having a lot of problems

This is my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.gmc.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.gmc.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

My Dao

```
public interface AtividadesDao {

    void save(Atividades a);

    void edit(Atividades a,int id);

    void deleteById(int id);

    List listAllAtividades();

}
```

My DaoImpl

```
@Repository("atividadesDao")
public class AtividadesDaoImpl implements AtividadesDao{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AtividadesDaoImpl.class);


    private final SessionFactory session;

    @Autowired
    public AtividadesDaoImpl(SessionFactory session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public static Date jodatToSQLDate(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return new Date(localDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Atividades a) {
        session.getCurrentSession();
        session.getCurrentSession().save(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(Atividades a, int id) {
        session.getCurrentSession();
        Atividades atividades = (Atividades) session.getCurrentSession().get(Atividades.class, a.getIdAtividades());
        atividades.setAtividade(a.getAtividade());
        atividades.setLocal(a.getLocal());
        atividades.setDescricao(a.getDescricao());
        atividades.setObjetivos(a.getObjetivos());
        atividades.setPeriodo(a.getPeriodo());
        atividades.setPrevisaoMes(a.getPrevisaoMes());
        atividades.setDataPrevista(a.getDataPrevista());
        atividades.setHora(a.getHora());
        atividades.setOrcamento(a.getOrcamento());
        atividades.setDestinatarios(a.getDestinatarios());
        atividades.setObservacoes(a.getObservacoes());
        session.getCurrentSession().update(atividades);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        Atividades atividades = (Atividades) session.getCurrentSession().get(Atividades.class, id);
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List listAllAtividades() {
        session.openSession();
        return session.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM atividades").list();
    }
}
```

My Service

public interface AtividadesService {

```
    void save(Atividades a);

    void edit(Atividades a,int id);

    void deleteById(int id);

    List<Atividades> listAllAtividades();
}
```

My ServiceImpl

```
@SuppressWarnings("DefaultFileTemplate")
@Service("atividadesService")
@Transactional
public class AtividadesServiceImpl implements AtividadesService {

    private final AtividadesDao ad;

    @Autowired
    public AtividadesServiceImpl(AtividadesDao ad) {
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Atividades a) {
        ad.save(a);

    }

    @Override
    public void edit(Atividades a, int id) {
        ad.edit(a, id);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        ad.deleteById(id);

    }

    @Override
    public List<Atividades> listAllAtividades() {
        return ad.listAllAtividades();
    }
}
```

And finally my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    AtividadesService as;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        //Lista as atividades da semana
        List<Atividades> atividades = as.listAllAtividades();
        model.addAttribute("atividades", atividades);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have no errors now but i have a 404 error "The requested resource is not available."
My index.jsp is inside WEB-INF/views
This is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gmc")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /*@Autowired
    RoleToUserProfileConverter roleToUserProfileConverter;*/

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
//        registry.addConverter(roleToUserProfileConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `No identifier specified for entity: com.gmc.model.AppUserUserProfile` this entity has issue(s) with the Id definition.  Post that code if you still cannot resolve it

Comment: check my update

Comment: What is the URL you are using to get your index? You are mapping /index at controller level and also at the method level, so it should be http://yourcontext/index/index

Comment: fixed...Thanks to all